# Adding blur to box-reflect possible?

Tags: css, filter, css-animations

I am curious if this is possible. I have a pen I’m working on and am currently using 100 divs to replicate the reflection of 100 other divs. If I could add blur to the actual box-reflect then I could alleviate having the extra 100 divs playing the role of the reflection.

I hope that makes sense. [Here](https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/QWNXQVW) is the CodePen, view in Chrome on desktop for best results. Firefox is not supported.

```
 -webkit-box-reflect: below -38px linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(
          255,
          255,
          255,
          0.5
        )
        0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70%);
```

Comment: You want a reflect effect with a blur? I think an alternative, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/nxv057c4/) would probably be easier. If that's a viable alternative I can write it up in an answer.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my write up. I only want the sparks themselves to have a blur not the reflection of the word sparks. 

Currently the way I have it is exactly how I want it but was wondering if it could be achieved without the extras divs acting as the reflection.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, hopefully someone can take a look and help you out with it - it's a very cool looking effect

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to recreate this effect to and figured it out. The key is to make a pseudo element (::after) and position it right over the shadow. Then apply backdrop-filter: blur(Ypx) to the ::after.